# jQuery qTip plugin without mouseover

Tags: jquery, qtip

Im just trying to put some simple validation on an input type="text" when the user clicks a button it checks the length of the field if its less than 2 characters I want a qTip to open/show.

I DO NOT want it to display on mouseover I don't wan't it to display when the user is typing in the field. Only when this happens

```
$('#myfield').length > 0 && $('#myfield').length > 3){
     // open tool tip
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('#myfield').val().length`?

Comment: yes I'm sorry $('#myfield').val().length

Answer (score 0):

You need qTip2 for registering click event with this plugin.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

### JQuery

```
$(function () {

            function openQTip(clickedElement, contentValue)
            {
                $(clickedElement).qtip({
                   content: contentValue,
                   show: 'click',
                   hide: 'mouseout'
                });
            }

            $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){

                var valueLength = $('input[type="text"]').val().length;

                if(valueLength > 0 && valueLength < 2)
                {
                    openQTip(this, 'not enough characters'); 
                }
                else
                {
                        //submit form
                }


                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have that part the issue is I want that //open qTip to  actually open a qtip. That is the actual question. And I want that qTip to NOT open on mouseover I only want it to open when opened via javascript not user interaction

Comment: I don't get it exactly. You need some validation plugin, instead of  you are using a tooltip plugin. The tooltip only works on that specific element. I editted my answer, but the validation message of the text input will be shown on the submit input. I editted my answer, but it's not good for validation.